Running commands as root in Puppeteer Docker container
I am using official Puppeteer Docker image to run my Node.js app
However, for my app to run well, I need to run some commands as root. The default user, pptruser, is not in sudoers list. It is not clear if the su password is documented. I am aware I can create a custom image and set up a special user through Dockerfile commands, but is that really the only way?

In your Dockerfile, you can switch to USER root and back as needed.  What setup steps do you need to do, and why can't you do them during an image build?
